# Open Street Map using OSMNX: how to retrieve bus routes?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

```
import osmnx as ox
ox.__version__ # '0.13.0'
```

I would like to show the [bus routes from the Open Street Map for Hannover](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/%C3%96PNVKarte)  on a map using OSMNX by retrieving them as ".**graph...**". E.g.:

```
G = ox.graph_from_place('Hannover, Germany', retain_all=False, truncate_by_edge=True,
                        simplify=True, network_type=None, custom_filter='["route"~"bus"]')
# returns EmptyOverpassResponse: There are no data elements in the response JSON
```

But I guess this only works for OSM [Nodes and Ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements), not for Relations? (and public transport routes are stored as relations)?

Therefore I use this workaround:

```
tags = {'route' : 'bus'}
gdfox = ox.pois_from_place('Hannover, Germany', tags)
gdfox.shape # (4022, 988)
gdfox['element_type'].value_counts() # node    2412, way     1610
```

This works but it is not perfect as there are some gaps in the routes:

[image: sample map with busroutes plotted from pois retrieved via tags]

Please advice if there is a better way?

Comment: Correct. Graph creation uses nodes/ways rather than relations. Can you look on OSM itself and tell me what specific elements are missing in the gaps you see? You probably just need to add a couple more tags into your `tags` dict for a successful poi query.

Comment: Thanks. So the answer is: 1. relations cannot be used for graph creation. And 2. use the right tags? 

-> Is it possible to use the gdf with pois (gdfox above) with osmnx.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs(gdf_nodes, gdf_edges) ? I splitted the above gdfox in gdf_nodes and gdf_ways and used that with graph_from_gdfs but get a type_error... 
I need to study NetworkX. 

I also wonder if kwargs  like "Simplify" that are available with "osmnx.graph.graph_from..." can be available with "graph_from_gdfs" too? (in an ideal world, fully appreciating all of the efforts already invested by you!)

Comment: No, the `graph_from_gdfs` function exists as the reciprocal of the `graph_to_gdfs` function: they allow you to convert an existing OSMnx-created MultiDiGraph to node/edge geopandas GeoDataFrames and back again. If there is a straightforward way to convert relations -> graphs, I'd be open to discussing if a PR is proposed on GitHub.