# OSMNX - Incomplete network

Tags: python, python-3.x, openstreetmap, geopandas, osmnx

I'm trying to retrieve the rail and subway network of a city.
In OSM, I checked that each station was properly tagged, but when I run my code, there are some missing stations, as well as part of the track (both stations and track on the west side of the subway line).

```
ox.config(use_cache=False,
      log_console=True,
      useful_tags_way=ox.settings.useful_tags_way + ['public_transport', 'railway'],
      useful_tags_node=ox.settings.useful_tags_node + ['public_transport', 'railway','highway','ref'])

cf='["railway"~"rail|subway|station"]'
graph=ox.graph_from_place('Turin,Italy', retain_all = True, custom_filter=cf)
nod, edg=ox.utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(graph)
```

I also tried with other cities with available data, but it still does not retrieve the whole network.

**SOLVED**:

Now I use:

```
graph=ox.graph_from_place(city, retain_all = True, custom_filter=cf, simplify=False)
```

Moreover, I get nodes rapresenting station by using a specfic command:

```
st=ox.geometries_from_place(city, tags=tag)
```

Comment: Perhaps provide some examples of OSM rail nodes you are not successfully retrieving that you expected you would have.

Comment: I handled the issues but I have a further question: how can I extract relations (and hence routes) from a list of bus stops? And, eventually, are these data collected in a database or as a graph ?

I read a similiar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067842/open-street-map-using-osmnx-how-to-retrieve-bus-routes), but I even haven't understood if it is possible to collect routes.

Comment: Short answer: using the geometries module, yes; using the graph module, no.