# OSMNX - When trying to get bus routes in my study area, I got empty df

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, osmnx

Why do I get an empty df using the same code as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067842/open-street-map-using-osmnx-how-to-retrieve-bus-routes#_=_), just changing the module's name from pois to geometries?
I'm using `0.16.0` version.

I also tried for different cities using different tag combinations, but I got nothing or a very very scattered network. I checked on osm and the network is actually there.

```
tags = {'route' : 'bus'}
gdfox = ox.geometries_from_place('Hannover, Germany', tags)
```

The resulting df is empty with only one column:

### unique_id

Comment: OpenStreetMap is incomplete, esp. regarding geometries like this. It is likely that there are simply no data to download.

Comment: No, they are. I checked in osm and the relation corresponding to the route i'm looking forward is correctly defined. Moreover, some months ago, in the post  I linked, same networks was available. Of course there might be some disconnections etc. but in my case no route at all is found

Comment: @GiuseppeBrenk see [this](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/pull/654#issuecomment-775531527) discussion on GitHub and the `geometries` module's [latest](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.geometries) docs. "You can use this module to query for nodes, ways, and relations (the latter of type 'multipolygon' or 'boundary' only)". See the linked conversation thread on GitHub for more background details. tl;dr you can retrieve any OSM geometries if they're nodes, ways, or multipolygon/boundary relations.